# In react, I`m using ant design library and inside "map" function using two <Row> tag, the key for the <Row> element is same and hence error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Warning message => react-dom.development.js:88 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `0`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

```
<Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off" >
                <Form.List name="users" initialValue={[{ccn: "",cn:"",title:"" ,major: "",year:""}]}>
                    {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
                    <>
                        {fields.map(field => (
                        <Space key={field.key} style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: 8 }} align="baseline">
                            <div>
                    <Row>
                            
                            <Form.Item
                            {...field}
                            name={[field.name, 'ccn']}
                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'ccn']}
                            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing ccn' }]}
                            >
                            <AutoComplete
                                    options={cocOptions}
                                    style={{
                                    width: 200,
                                    }}
                                    onSelect={oncocSelect}
                                    onSearch={oncocSearch}
                                    placeholder="Country of College/University"
                                />
                            </Form.Item>

                            <Form.Item
                            {...field}
                            name={[field.name, 'cn']}
                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'cn']}
                            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing cn name' }]}
                            >
                            <AutoComplete
                                options={cnOptions}
                                style={{
                                width: 200,
                                }}
                                onSelect={oncnSelect}
                                onSearch={oncnSearch}
                                placeholder="College/University Name"
                            />
                            </Form.Item>
                            </Row>
                            <Row>
                            <Form.Item
                            {...field}
                            name={[field.name, 'title']}
                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'title']}
                            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing title name' }]}
                            >
                            <Input placeholder="title Name" />
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item
                            {...field}
                            name={[field.name, 'major']}
                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'major']}
                            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing major name' }]}
                            >
                            <AutoComplete
                                    options={mOptions}
                                    style={{
                                    width: 200,
                                    }}
                                    onSelect={onmSelect}
                                    onSearch={onmSearch}
                                    placeholder="Major"
                                />
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item
                            {...field}
                            name={[field.name, 'year']}
                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'year']}
                            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing year name' }]}
                            >
                            <Select placeholder="Year" style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={handleChange}>
                            <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
                            <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>

                            <Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
                            </Select>
                            </Form.Item>
                            <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(field.name)} />
                            </Row>
                            </div>
                        </Space>
                        ))}
                        <Form.Item>
                        <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => add()} block icon={<PlusOutlined />}>
                            Add field
                        </Button>
                        </Form.Item>
                        
                        
                    </>
                    )}
                </Form.List>
                <Form.Item hidden>
                    <Button ref={myButton} type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                    Submit
                    </Button>
                </Form.Item>
                </Form>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?
All information is detailed in the warning